# Sending data from view to controller AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

how can I send the var lang to the controller so I can use it in partiel.  here is my shot:

```
  $("#search-select").on("click", function() {
    var lang = $('#search-select').dropdown('get value');
    $.get({
      url: translations_url
      data: lang,
      success: function(){
        console.log('data sent');
      }
    });
  });
```

**EDIT**

current code:

```
  $("#search-select").dropdown();

  $("#search-select").on("click", function() {
    var lang = $('#search-select').dropdown('get value');
    $.get({
      url: "#{translations_url}",
      dataType: "script",
      data: {
        lang: lang
      }
    });
  });
```

problem: params[:lang] still don't work in controller

Comment: its correct wht you written

Comment: Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery)

Comment: 1. Check if your js `lang` variable is not equal to `undefined`
2. Please, show us your params hash after AJAX request

Comment: @tbard here is the params hash after AJAX request: Parameters: {"lang"=>"cs", "_"=>"1526653165357"}

Answer (score 0):

Set correct `_path` to your **post** method:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '<%= controller_path %>', method: 'POST',
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))},
    data: { lang: lang },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Now you can work with `lang` in your controller

```
def method
  params[:lang] # do something
  answer = 'Then, you can return some data to view'
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: answer }
  end
end
```

Comment: Do you know how to get the controller_path ? and apparently i need  js.erb, do you have any idea what I need to write in it?

Comment: You see your routes from `rake routes` command. What is your goal?

Comment: well since I can't use translations_path, I'm using "#{translations_url}"

Comment: @Arb `<% environment.context_class.instance_eval { include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers } %>`

Answer (score 0):

you're missing , after url: translations_url, also if you can send data as JSON with key and value, like `data: {lang: 'value'}`, also you don't need to specify method name if you're using `GET`, see the below example

```
$.ajax({
  url: translations_url,
  data: {lang: 'value'},
  success: function(){
    console.log('data sent');
  }
});
```

if you need to use POST Method then include `method: 'post'` incase jquery ajax method doesn't call js.erb file you need to add `dataType: 'script'`

Comment: apparently I don't have a js.erb so do you know what I need to write in it ?

Comment: `$("#div_id").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'partial_name', locals: {lang: @lang})) %>");` try this in your js.erb file

Comment: I'm getting 500 error, xhr one,  what do you think it comes from?

Comment: check if your using the right route, controller action and the log of your application

Comment: I still can't use params[:lang] in the controller. (check the edit on the question)

Comment: `var lang = $('#search-select').dropdown('get value');` did you check what are you getting in lang?

Comment: Yes, i'm getting the languages that I want there.

Comment: check your log, what is going in parameters, also, try to debug by yourself

Answer (score -1):

You can't use route path helpers on the frontend. But you can send proper URL from backend to frontend via data-attribute:

```
#search-select{ data: { path: translations_url } }
```

And then in your `js`:

```
$("#search-select").on("click", function() {
    var url = $(this).data('path'),
        data = { lang: $(this).dropdown('get value') };

    $.get({
      url: url,
      data: data,
      success: function(){
        console.log('data sent');
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: I changed it, i'm using it like :
url: "#{translations_url}",